# error when graphing corr: Vspace error nonfunction with margintop in R

Tags: r

Error in app$vspace(new_style$`margin-top` %||% 0) :
attempt to apply non-function

I am trying to plot a correlation matrix. I am not sure why I am getting this error, but all my packages are up to date.

```
library(corrplot)
data <- read.csv("data.csv")

data%>%
mutate(positivity_rate = as.numeric(positivity_rate))%>%
mutate(newcases = as.numeric(newcases))%>%
select("win_pct", "Wins", "Losses", "positivity_rate", "weekly_newcases_per100k")%>%
mutate(positivity_rate = as.numeric(positivity_rate))%>%
mutate(newcases = as.numeric(newcases))%>%
drop_na()%>%
group_by(school)%>%
summarize(positivity_rate = mean(positivity_rate,na.rm=TRUE))%>%
summarize(newcases = mean(weekly_newcases_per100k,na.rm=TRUE))

df2 <- mutate_all(data, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
cor(df2)

corrplot(cor(df2), method="shade",shade.col=NA, tl.col="black", tl.srt=45)
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible code and data using `dput` for data?

Comment: Win, Losses are integers, positivity_rate and new_cases are characters. I think the problems is the character variables.